# Display Location in DetailTextLabel

Tags: ios, location, tableview

I am building an iphone app that displays posts in a table view. Each post is tagged with the user's current location, which I am struggling to display in the detail text label.
The post model includes these properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *content;
@property (strong) CLLocation *location;
```

In the index view I configure the cell like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Post *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.text = post.content;
```

This returns the content of the post properly.
However when I try to include the lat/lng in the subtitle, it crashes.
This causes a crash and raises an incompatible pointer types exception "NSString from CLLocation":

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = post.location;
```

This makes sense because .text is expecting a string and location is initialized in a dictionary like so:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.content = [dictionary valueForKey:@"content"];
    self.location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dictionary nonNullValueForKeyPath:@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[[dictionary nonNullValueForKeyPath:@"lng"] doubleValue]];

    return self;
}
```

So how can I return the location in the subtitle label?
I will also want to display a timestamp and suspect it is a similar solution.
In my post model implementation file I #import "ISO8601DateFormatter.h" to format string from date, and similarly I have:

```
static NSString * NSStringFromCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate) {
    return [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
}
```

But I am not sure how to tie this all into a simple detailTextLabel.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

I made this amount of progress:
The lat and lng displays integers- but it is not the proper lat/lng i.e. it isn't actually reading the correct integers.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"at (%f, %f)", post.location];
```

The lat and lng displayed is this:
0.00, -1.9
when it should be:
lat":"37.785834","lng":"-122.406417.
So its not actually reading the end of the line that says "post.location"
So how can I get it to display the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.

```
   - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        Post *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text  = NSStringFromCoordinate(post.location);
        //.....more setup code
    }
```

Comment: That raises the exception: implicit conversion of int to NSString is disallowed with ARC.

Comment: you're trying to use a string where it expects an int. which lines does it occur on?

Comment: I added some progress above

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"at (%f, %f)", post.location.coordinate.latitude,post.location.coordinate.longitude];

Comment: that gives you the individual double values from the coordinate of the location

Comment: Stop your debugger and inspect the variables.